# dynamo db FilterExpression, find in json object using value as key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

It is possible to somehow filter results by key name that stored in the same object?
I have JSON object "keys", in property "default" stored key of the object that I need. Is it somehow possible to filter like that `keys[keys.default].type = some_type`?

```
    var params = {
    TableName: 'TABLE_NAME',
    IndexName: 'TABLE_INDEX', // optional (if querying an index)
    KeyConditionExpression: 'myId = :value', 
    FilterExpression: '#kmap[#kmap.#def].#tp = :keyval', 
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {names with special characters
        '#kmap': 'keys',
        '#tp': 'type',
        '#def': 'default'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { // a map of substitutions for all attribute values
        ':value': '1',
        ':keyval': 'some_type'
      },
    Limit: 10, // optional (limit the number of items to evaluate)

    ProjectionExpression: "displayName, #kmap",

    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTLAL', // optional (NONE | TOTAL | INDEXES)
};
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

This `keys[keys.default]` is not even valid json, as far as I can tell.

Of course, you can do this in two steps:

1. First, query to get the default key
2. Then query to get the value

Don't forget, filters are obly applied to the result set - it still requires a libear traversal as specified by your Query or Scan operation.

So you can probably more easily run your *query* on the client.

And lastly, if this is a typical query ypu need to perform, as an optimization, you can lift the default key and value to be top level attributes on the item. Thrn you can actually create a GSI on that attribure and can actually do efficient lookups.